# запись полей input в массив

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="field"/>
<input type="text" class="field"/>
<input type="text" class="field"/>
......
```

таких полей может быть от `1..n`. Как записать все данные из полей в массив и посмотреть его содержимое.Пробовал так

js

```
(function (){
inp = d.getElementsByClassName('field');
        var mas = [];
        function save(){
            for (var i=0; i< inp.length; i++){                
                    mas[i]=inp[i].value;                          
            }          
        }   
})();
```

но через консоль абсолютно ничего не выводится.

Comment: А функцию `save()` как вызываете?

Comment: В цикле `for`, после присвоения `mas[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если инициализировать переменную `d`, которой присвоить `document`, если вызвать фунцкию `save()` и сделать вывод в консоль, то всё замечтательно работает:

```js
(function() {
  var d = document,
    inp = d.getElementsByClassName('field'),
    mas = [];

  function save() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      mas[i] = inp[i].value;
    }
    console.log(mas);
  }
  save();
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field" value="a" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="b" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="c" />
```

P.S. Кстати, я бы рекомендовал использовать `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` вместо `getElementsByClassName` и добавлять элементы в массив методом `push()`, хотя, это второстепенно

**UPD**

> а если такие инпуты добавлять блоками

Вы б уже всё нам рассказали, а то "*если*" могут не закончится.

```js
var arr = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.input_block'), function(block) {
  return [].map.call(block.querySelectorAll('.field'), function(inp) {
    return inp.value;
  });
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="input_block">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="a1">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="b1">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="c1">
</div>
<div class="input_block">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="a2">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="b2">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="c2">
</div>
```

Comment: про вызов функции видимо совсем забыл, спасибо)

Comment: хотя а если такие инпуты добавлять блоками (в каждом из которых по 3 инпута), то как тогда записывать в тот же масив, другой массив из элементов инпутов

Comment: @ddeadlink , дополнил в ответе

Comment: "если" исчерпаны, благодарствую за ответы )

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
  var d = document,
    inp = d.getElementsByClassName('field'),
    mas = [];

  function save() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      mas[i] = inp[i].value;
    }
    console.log(mas);
  }
  save();
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field" value="a" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="b" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="c" />
```